# Using encrypted password to send mail is failing

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I'm trying to use a stored encrypted password in a script that sends an email but I keed getting the error:

> send-mailmessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM 
>   [DM6PR66666019.namprd456.prod.outlook.com]

I used the following code to create the text file:

```
$passwordtostore = 'NotTheRealPassword$9gv8z6VHnPfDd8zc'
$secureStringPWD = $passwordtostore | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$secureStringText = $secureStringPWD | ConvertFrom-SecureString
Set-Content "c:\temp\scriptsencrypted_password1.txt" $secureStringText
```

I use the following to import the password:

```
$passwordFile = "c:\temp\scriptsencrypted_password1.txt"
$password = Get-Content $passwordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString
```

Here's the sendmail function I am using:

```
function SendMail($ToEmails,$FromEmail,$Subj,$Body,$UserName,$Password){
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $UserName,$Password

    $MailParams=@{"from"=$FromEmail; "to"=$ToEmails;"body"=$Body;"subject"=$Subj;"smtpserver"="smtp.office365.com"}

    send-mailmessage @MailParams -Credential $cred -UseSsl $true -port 587
}
```

Here's the code which calls the function:

```
$alertEmail = "me.stillme@mydomain.com"
$username="psemail@mydomain.com"
$passwordFile = "c:\temp\scriptsencrypted_password1.txt"
$password = Get-Content $passwordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $password)

Import-Module -Name "..\SendMail.psm1"

... Doing some stuff

SendMail $alertEmail $username "This is the subject" "this is the body" $credential.UserName $credential.Password
```

Comment: Is it wise to store the encrypted password in a text file? I have a similar [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76856629/13791079). Even if we store the encrypted password in a text file, anybody can see the encrypted password in the file and the decryption login in the script and can get the actual password, right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues with my code above:

1. An unescaped $ in the password.
2. Once I added " -NoNewline" to the set-content, it began to work.

So, to create the encrypted file:

```
$passwordtostore = "7K9CBgvc4rttvfctrsef6PVHqnP6fDdwhatevervtfdscttzSc"
$secureStringPWD = $passwordtostore | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$secureStringText = $secureStringPWD | ConvertFrom-SecureString
Set-Content "D:\Powershell Scripts\encrypted.hash" $secureStringText -NoNewline
```

Then to retrieve the password and use it in a credential:

```
$password = Get-Content $passwordFile -Raw | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($username, $password)
```

It wasn't the source of the issue, but I did implement @Theo's suggestion re: using send-mailmessage.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I fail to see why you would make a function in a module you need to import for the Send-MailMessage cmdlet..
This makes things a lot harder to use.

Also, it kind of looks like you are switching the emailaddresses To and From inside the function.

Anyway, things go wrong when you are creating the credentials, split it into username and (secure) password to send as parameters to the function and recombine them into a credentials object in there.

Why not skip that module function and simply do:

```
$password = Get-Content 'c:\temp\scriptsencrypted_password1.txt' -Raw | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential('YourLoginName', $password)
$MailParams=@{
    From       = 'me.stillme@mydomain.com'
    To         = 'psemail@mydomain.com'
    Body       = "this is the body"
    Subject    = "This is the subject"
    SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
    Port       = 587
    UseSsl     = $true
    Credential = $credential
}

Send-MailMessage @MailParams
```

This will make your script far more readable/maintainable

Comment: Get the error "ConvertTo-SecureString : Input string was not in a correct format:". If I add "-AsPlainText -Force" after ConvertTo-SecureString, that goes away, but I still get the same error as before.

Comment: @Michael Then.. are you sure the password in the textfile is correct and belongs to the username you are using? No whitespaces in there or blank lines?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I am. The issue must have to do with the encrypted password because it works if I use plain text. You can see the method I used to encrypt above; do you see anything wrong with it? And I am testing on the same computer where I generated the file. I even tried generating the file within the script, just in case the windows user was different for the script that was running vs who I was logged in as; no joy.

Comment: @Michael I cannot reproduce this.. Tried different methods: `$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential -ArgumentList 'LoginName', $password` and `$credential = [System.Management.Automation.PsCredential]::new('LoginName', $password)` and both work. However, since you're reading from a file, this may have to do with the encoding of that file. How did you save the pasword to file? Have you thought of saving the credentials with `Export-CliXml` ?