# How to securely store a password for a script run every day using a Windows task scheduler?

Tags: powershell, password-encryption

I have written a PowerShell script to do some operation. When the operation is completed, I want the script to send a mail using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet.

For this I used Google's app password feature. But I'm not confident about storing the app password as plain text in the script itself. I can encrypt somehow and store it in the script or separate file, but people can still see that password. Even if I encrypt the password, the decryption login will be there in the script itself. One other way I think would be useful is passing the encrypted password as an environment variable but 1. I couldn't find how to do that, 2. I still don't think that's safe as people can inspect the environment variables.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

[**The general approach of dealing with credentials is to avoid them and instead rely on other means to authenticate, such as certificates or Windows authentication.**](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md)

As you apparently found out yourself, trying to script a [single factor authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) either ends up in a [catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic)) or isn't secure as everybody that has access to your script has access to the key no matter how deep you to hide it using [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

If you aren't able to change the authentication way of the application, the safest practical way is probably to create your own "[single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on)" in means of using the Windows [DPAPI (Data Protection API)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) where the encryption is based on the computer and the user credentials.

For this you might use the PowerShell [ConvertTo-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring) and [ConvertFrom-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring) cmdlets.
First create a secure string (under the concerned computer/user account):

```
Read-Host 'Enter your password' -AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

This will return a string like:

```
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb01000000da4b9d0c09bdb140b3060606f3557e1200000000020000000000106600000001000020000000319f97dca4698fd8848b183e0a7e3fa26127043f68b75ed0ffad6e60eee59201000000000e8000000002000020000000e7f6f6c563f442ef7563967ab907abd528147e1cb8d03efdb4892f29ecbe38d3100000003098dedec04172048148654f5846bbcd40000000d270797bc32ba3d42a217d26dc1395b4bbf4fb4a9f9fe701b98270e1db848de3b048c36a792061fea06e1123b0288d687ffdda2ae934f63f60d58a8c19631007
```

> ⚠️ warning
> The contents of a SecureString are not encrypted on non-Windows systems.

You might put this string in an environment variable or somewhere else or even simply embed this in your script:

```
$EncryptedPassword = '01000000d08c9ddf...
```

> Note that this string can only be decrypted on the specific computer and by the user account that created the `$EncryptePassword`. This limitation adds in fact the security (also knowing that everytime you use the `ConvertFrom-SecureString` command you will get a different string).

To reveal the plain text password in your script you might do something like:

```
$Password = $EncryptedPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

Note that you actually should try to avoid to use the above command as that reveals the password and might leave memory traces. Therefore it is a good thing to at least remove the decrypted variables, e.g.: `Remove-Variable Password`.

#### Encrypting your script

You could even consider to DPAPI encrypt your whole script including hardcoded plain passwords (which actually better secures it than using tools as `PS2EXE`):

- `Protect-Script.ps1`

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string] $Path,
    [switch] $AsBase64
)
$Item = Get-Item $Path
if ($Item) {
    $OutPath = "$($Item.DirectoryName)\$($Item.BaseName).Protected$($Item.Extension)"
    $ScriptBlock = Get-Content -Raw -Path $Path
    $Hex = $ScriptBlock | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString
    if ($AsBase64) {
        $Bytes = [byte[]] -split ($Hex -replace '..', '0x$& ')
        $Base64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
        Set-Content -Path $OutPath "`$Base64 = '$Base64'"
        Add-Content -Path $OutPath '$Bytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64)'
        Add-Content -Path $OutPath '$Hex = -Join $Bytes.Foreach{ $_.ToString("x2") }'
    }
    else {
        Set-Content -Path $OutPath "`$Hex = '$Hex'"
    }
    Add-Content -Path $OutPath '$ScriptBlock = $Hex | ConvertTo-SecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText'
    Add-Content -Path $OutPath 'Invoke-Expression $ScriptBlock'
    Add-Content -Path $OutPath 'Remove-Variable Base64, Bytes, Hex, ScriptBlock -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue'
}
```

**Usage:**

```
.\Protect-Script.ps1 .\MailMessage.ps1 -AsBase64

.\MailMessage.Protected.ps1
```

Again: the `.\MailMessage.Encrypted.ps1` script will only work on the computer and the account were it was created.

Comment: @SomeshwaranS, not sure whether I answered your question as I would expect that [google app passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) has it's own Single-Sign-On features *unless* you are trying to *share* your passwords (which is a bad idea) meaning: running the scheduled tasks under each logged-in user account. (where the above solution won't work either)...

Comment: Hi @iRon, thanks for the detailed answer, I appreciate your help. TBH a lot of the terms you've mentioned here are quite advanced for me, but I'll go through the links. But even with the encrypted script approach, people will be able to decrypt the file, right? I'll be running this script in a remote machine which is accessed by others as well. I think I have to try something completely different.

Comment: @SomeshwaranS,  "*But even with the encrypted script approach, people will be able to decrypt the file, right?*". No, the script can only be decrypted (and will only run) under the same account and computer where it was created.

Answer (score 0):

I simply save it as a .xml file and then import it in scripts.

```
Save password to xml file:
$credentials = Get-Credential user@domain.com
$credentials | Export-CliXml -Path 'C:\filepath\passwordfile.xml'

To Import it:
$credentials = Import-Clixml 'C:\filepath\passwordfile.xml'
```

Your password file will look like this:
[image]